# using <div> <form> and GET together?

Tags: php, html, css

i have a home page which has navigation sidebar and a search bar. if i modify the code to make search work navigation wont work and vice versa. Heres the code. Please help

```
<div class="w3-bar w3-black">
  <a href="home.php" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Home</a>
  <a href="msg.php" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Message</a>
  <a href="frnd.php" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Friends</a>
  <a href="notify.php" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Notification</a>
  <div class="w3-dropdown-hover">
    <button class="w3-button">Dropdown</button>
    <div class="w3-dropdown-content w3-bar-block w3-card-4">
      <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Settings</a>
      <a href="logout.php" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Log-Out</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <form action="result.php" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="query" class="w3-bar-item w3-input" style="color:#000" placeholder="Search.."/>
    <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-green">GO</button>
</div>
```

right now when i click the navigation bar icon. it goes to search result. and with GET method and the form tag navbar will not open.

Comment: when i change the <button> tag to <a> tag and remove the <form> tag navigation works but not the search.

Answer (score 2):

You should close the form tag

```
<form action="result.php" method="GET">
  <input type="text" name="query" class="w3-bar-item w3-input" style="color:#000" placeholder="Search.."/>
  <button type="submit"  class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-green">GO</button>

</form>
```

otherwise the form is not well formed  and can't submit the values

and add  the type submit to the button

Answer (score 1):

Better, your code will be looks like this

```
    <div class="w3-bar w3-black">
    <a href="home.php" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Home</a>
    <a href="msg.php" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Message</a>
    <a href="frnd.php" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Friends</a>
    <a href="notify.php" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Notification</a>
    <div class="w3-dropdown-hover">
    <button class="w3-button">Dropdown</button>
    <div class="w3-dropdown-content w3-bar-block w3-card-4">
      <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Settings</a>
      <a href="logout.php" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Log-Out</a>
    </div>
    </div>
    <?php if(isset($_GET['query'])): ?>
    <form action="result.php" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="query" class="w3-bar-item w3-input" style="color:#000" placeholder="Search.."/>
    <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-green">GO</button>
</form>
    <?php endif ?>
    </div>
```

hope this answer will help you out from your problem

Comment: Please don´t give "code only" answers, explain your solution. Btw, you are not closing the form tag.

Comment: that the search box is not seen until 'query' value is set. and you need search box to set 'query' value. but your code helped. thanks